# Angularjs 2 и jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular2

Как правильно подключить jQuery к проекту на AngularJS 2?

Comment: но зачем? в большинстве случаев можно обойтись встроенными средствами

Answer (score 0):

исходник [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2), можно посмотреть, как все правильно настроить

```
interface JQuery {
    chosen(options?:any):JQuery;
}
```